# strange behavior of cast object to decimal c sharp

Tags: c#, casting, behavior

I ran with strangeness:

```
var k = (decimal?)(int?)1; //valid cast
var p = (decimal?)(int?)(object)(int?)1; //valid cast
var l = (decimal?)(object)(int?)1; //Specified cast is not valid
```

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: `(decimal?)(object)1` - Specified cast is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first cast is:

- Convert `int` to `int?`
- Convert `int?` to `decimal?`

Both conversions are valid.

The second case is:

- Convert `int` to `int?`
- Box the `int?` (which ends up as a boxed `int`)
- Unbox the object to `int?`
- Convert `int?` to `decimal?`

All of these conversions are valid.

The third case is:

- Convert `int` to `int?`
- Box the `int?` (which ends up as a boxed `int`)
- Unbox the object to `decimal?`

The last conversion here is invalid - you can only unbox to the same value type or its nullable equivalent. (Actually the CLR is somewhat more forgiving than this, but that's not relevant in this case.)

The conversion to `int?` in each case is actually irrelevant. The unboxing to a nullable type is somewhat irrelevant too, in that unboxing to a nullable type is like unboxing to a non-nullable type, except that a null reference is unboxed to a null value. Given that there are no null values here, your final example is equivalent to:

```
object o = 1; // Boxing
decimal d = (decimal) o; // Unboxing, but to the wrong type
```